# Как разместить элементы начиная с определённой колонки bootstrap 4

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap4

Вообщем начинаю учить bootstrap, столкнулся с проблемой:
[image: Скриншот]

Должно выглядеть вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите `header`, именно кнопки не получатся такими же, пробовал через `margin` (костылями), пробовал через `margin` самого `bootstrap`, делал размер колонок другим, но не получалось.
Ответа в интернете я так и не нашёл, может не так вопрос поставил, но ответы были совсем не те, что мне нужны, вот код `html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Blitz</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row myrow">
                <div class="col-sm-2 mycol" id="fontHeaderF">
                    Blitz
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2  mycol headerB">
                    <div class="col-sm mycol headerBL">
                        HOMEPAGE
                    </div>
                    HOME
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 mycol headerB">
                    <div class="col-sm mycol headerBL">
                        WHO ARE WE?
                    </div>
                    ABOUT
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 mycol headerB">
                    <div class="col-sm mycol headerBL">
                        MY PORTFOLIO
                    </div>
                    PROJECTS
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 mycol headerB">
                    <div class="col-sm mycol headerBL">
                        LATEST NEWS
                    </div>
                    BLOG
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 mycol headerB">
                    <div class="col-sm mycol headerBL">
                        GET IN TOUCH
                    </div>
                    CONTACT
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Вот `css`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Pacifico;
    src: url(../fonts/Pacifico.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Bebas;
    src: url(../fonts/bebas_light.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: BebasB;
    src: url(../fonts/bebas_bold.ttf);
}
#fontHeaderF {
    font-family: Pacifico;
    font-size: 2.6vw;
}
.headerB {
    font-family: BebasB;
    font-size: 1.6vw;
}
.headerBL {
    font-family: Bebas;
    font-size: 1vw;
}
.myrow {
    margin-left: 0; 
    margin-right: 0;
}
.mycol {
    padding-left: 0; 
    padding-right:0;
}
```

Прошу объяснить, что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `row` заворачиваешь два `col`-а, первый на `col-sm-5`, второй на `col-sm-7`.

В первом остается только блиц, а во втором остальное.

Comment: В этом случае кнопки встают в колонку, а не в линию.

Comment: так внутри тоже row и снова колы на каждую